# Using same calculation for different SQL Aliases

Tags: sql, alias

so I have two column aliases that are using the same calculation:

`,case when bi.PolicyFeeFactor = 0
        then 0
      else 
        CAST(ROUND(nb.AnnualPolicyFee * bi.PolicyFeeFactor,2)AS DECIMAL(6,2))
      end
as UNIT_POLFEE_Y`

`,case when bi.PolicyFeeFactor = 0 
        then 0
      else 
        CAST(ROUND(nb.AnnualPolicyFee * bi.PolicyFeeFactor,2)AS DECIMAL(6,2))
      end
as UNIT_PUPFEE_Y`

I am looking for a way where I can just write the calculation once and create both column aliases from that one statement eg:

`,case when bi.PolicyFeeFactor = 0 
        then 0
      else 
        CAST(ROUND(nb.AnnualPolicyFee * bi.PolicyFeeFactor,2)AS DECIMAL(6,2))
      end
as UNIT_PUPFEE_Y, UNIT_POLFEE_Y`

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it inside a subquery, ex

```
SELECT Result AS UNIT_PUPFEE_Y, 
       Result AS UNIT_POLFEE_Y
FROM
    (
        SELECT CASE .... END AS Result
        FROM   tableName
    ) s
```

Comment: This works when I only select one expression from the subquery, but when I select both expressions I get the error: `Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS`

Comment: did you executed the same query which is given above?

Answer (score 0):

You may write like this,

```
SELECT *,UNIT_PULFEE_Y AS UNIT_PUPFEE_Y FROM
(SELECT *
,case when bi.PolicyFeeFactor = 0 then 0 else CAST(ROUND(nb.AnnualPolicyFee *              bi.PolicyFeeFactor,2)AS DECIMAL(6,2)) end as UNIT_PULFEE_Y
FROM Table )A
```